# Continuity of $xy^3/(x^2+y^6)$ at $(x,y)=(0,0)$

Tags: limits, continuity

Let $f(x, y) = \frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^6}$ if $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$  and $f(0,0) = 0$.
Is this function continuous at $(x,y) = (0,0)$?

I believe that it is, because the function appears to be approaching $0$ as $(x, y) \to (0,0)$, and the hole is filled there, but I'm not sure how to prove that the limit is $0$.

Comment: what will happen if we change the powers in the denominator, I mean $\frac{xy^3}{x^6+y^2}$

Comment: @hossein About 6 years late there, friend

Comment: Is this function bounded in $\mathbb{R}^2$ if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=y^3$ therefore we have
$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^6}=\lim\limits_{y\to0}\frac{y^6}{2y^6}=\frac{1}{2} \ \ \ (1)$$ and if we consider $x=y$ then 
$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^6}=0  \ \ \ \ (2)$$ so that from (1) and (2)  we see that limit don't exits. Therefore the function is not continuous.

Answer (score 4):

if we take the path $x=my^3$ we have:

$$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{my^6}{m^2y^6+y^6}=\frac{m}{m^2+1}$$
which depends on $m$. Hence limit does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

What happens when you take the limit along the path $y = x^{1/3}$?

Comment: you get the limit to equal 1/2, correct? So that means that the limit doesn't exist and the function is not continuous?

Comment: Exactly. IF you go along the path $x=0$, you get that the limit is 0, and for the limit to exist, you must get the same value for all paths.

Answer (score 1):

Just to mention, that an important fact of this example is that for every $v\in\mathbb{R}^2$ which is not $0$ then $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{v}}(0,0)=0$ but as wrote above, the function is even not continous at the origin